# How to get Elasticsearch aggregates to ignore filters the in similar way as Solr facets

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, elasticsearch-aggregation

In Solr, [you can keep the counts for certain facets despite filters being set](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters). Is there a way to enable similar functionality for Elasticsearch Aggregates?

(I have found a few examples for the now discontinued Elasticsearch facets, but i think this question has to be answered once more for Aggregates.)

Example:

```
q=*      q=foo   q=foo        q=foo&filter=A:2,B:1
                 &filter=A:2                     
AggA     AggA    AggB         AggB
1(10)    1(5)    *2(5)*       *2(5)*
2(10)    2(5)
3(10)    1(10)

AggB     AggB    AggB         AggB
1(10)    1(5)    1(5)         *1(3)*
2(10)    2(5)    2(5)         2(5)
3(10)    3(0)    3(5)         3(5)
```

I got a suggestion on trying [Global Aggretion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html), but the only way i can get Global Aggregation to work is like this (AggB being configured as a Global Aggregate):

```
    q=*      q=foo   q=foo        q=foo&filter=A:2,B:1
                     &filter=A:2                     
    AggA     AggA    AggB         AggB
    1(10)    1(5)    *2(5)*       *2(5)*
    2(10)    2(5)
    3(10)    1(10)

    AggB     AggB    AggB         AggB
    1(10)    1(10)    1(10)         1(10)
    2(10)    2(10)    2(10)         2(10)
    3(10)    3(10)    3(10)         3(10)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example (data sample, mapping, query) of what you are looking for?

Comment: Examples added.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with [global aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html).

It does not allow as much flexibility as Solr, as in Solr you can have many tags and exclude only some of them, but the functionality is there.

Comment: Great! I will try it out straight away

Comment: It seems to me that the global aggregates does not take any part of the query into consideration. Or has things improved since version 2.4?

Comment: things change fast in ES with each version...it's difficult to say